# Unable to pass the variable to the next paginated table after clicking next on the paginated table

Tags: php

```html
<html>

<head>

  <script>
   
    //insert value into the html input element value
    function addStartDateToTable(dates, dateLoc) {
      var ndate = document.getElementById(dates).value;
      var datel = document.getElementById(dateLoc).value;
      document.getElementById(dateLoc).value = datel + ndate + " 00:00:00\"";

    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <form style="display: inline">
    <p>Please Enter Date:</p>
    <input type="date" class="date" id="date1" onchange="addStartDateToTable('date1','preview1');" <!--function will activate automatically when date has changes--> required="true">
  </form>
  <form method="POST" action="paginationT.php" target="_blank" style="display: inline"><!--This is where the value from-->
    <input type="hidden" id="preview1" name="tval" value="afdata,SlipNo,LotNo,Description,R09outtime,&quot;" <!--value that is uses to split and run SQL query-->>
    <input type="submit" name="preview" value="PREVIEW" onchange="this.form.submit()">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Pagination</title>

</head>

<body>
  <?php

                if (isset($_GET['pageno'])) {
                    $pageno = $_GET['pageno'];
                } else {
                    $pageno = 1;
                }
                $no_of_records_per_page = 10;`limited to 10 rows per table `
                $offset = ($pageno-1) * $no_of_records_per_page;

                $string=$_POST['tval']; //parameter that is passed from another page's form input
                $tableValue=explode(",",$string);//spliting the data to let it become usable for the SQL query
       define("tableName",$tableValue[0]);//define as constant
     define("slipNo",$tableValue[1]);//define as constant
    define("lotNo",$tableValue[2]);//define as constant
    define("desc",$tableValue[3]);//define as constant
    define("con",$tableValue[4]);//define as constant
    define("startDate",$tableValue[5]);//try to define value as constant
 $sql="SELECT COUNT(".con.") FROM ".tableName. " WHERE ". con.">=".startDate; //insert string into vaiable
            define("QUERY",$sql);//define SQL code as constant

            $total_pages_sql = QUERY;
                echo $total_pages_sql; //display the sql for checking convenience, become blank after switching the table page
                $result = mysqli_query($conn,$total_pages_sql);
                $total_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)[0];
                $total_pages = ceil($total_rows / $no_of_records_per_page);

                $sql = "SELECT ".slipNo.",".lotNo.",".desc." FROM ".tableName." LIMIT $offset, $no_of_records_per_page"; //using defined constant to run the query 
                $res_data = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                echo "<table border=\"1px\" width=\"500\">
                <tr><th>Slip No</th><th>Lot No</th><th>Description</th></tr>";
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res_data)){
                 echo "<tr><td>".$row[slipNo] ."</td><td>". $row[lotNo]. "</td><td>". $row[desc]. "</td></tr>";//looping the table
                }
               echo "</table>";
                mysqli_close($conn);
             ?>
<!--This is the buttons for switching pages-->`buttons for switching pages of data`
    <ul class="pagination">
      <li><a href="?pageno=1">First</a></li>
      <li class="<?php if($pageno <= 1){ echo 'disabled'; } ?>">
        <a href="<?php if($pageno <= 1){ echo '#'; } else { echo " ?pageno=".($pageno - 1); } ?>">Prev</a>
      </li>
      <li class="<?php if($pageno >= $total_pages){ echo 'disabled'; } ?>">
        <a href="<?php if($pageno >= $total_pages){ echo '#'; } else { echo " ?pageno=".($pageno + 1); } ?>">Next</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="?pageno=<?php echo $total_pages; ?>">Last</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

[This is the first page of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPzb1.png)
      [This is what happen after I click next, the SQL code become blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IxEl.png)

```
<!-- end snippet -->

<!-- end snippet -->
```

i had tried to define those variables as constant

Hope all the data can be load on the paginated page, but only the first page can be loaded, when i click next on the paginated table those defined variable become blank it wont pass it to the next page and it just stuck there

Comment: It seems $_POST['tval'] is empty. Try to print $_POST['tval'].

Comment: where should I place it?